# jquery in js wordpress comment my php code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I add in wordpress theme ligne jquery to add searching icon

```
  jQuery(".mobmenur-container").after("<div>"+<?php echo do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter taxonomies='category,post_tag']' ); ?> +"</div>"");
```

[image: what i get]

I add in wordpress theme ligne jquery to add searching icon

Comment: why you use jquery to add this?

Comment: what i can use to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery runs in client-browser, meanwhile PHP is backend-side programming language. That's why this approach is just impossible to implement.

You can use correct approach instead.

F.e.

Run this shortcode inside hidden div, then grab that div's inner html and append anywhere you want.

```
<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">
<?php 
  echo do_shortcode( '[searchandfilter taxonomies="category,post_tag"]' );
?>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery(".mobmenur-container").after(
         jQuery("#hidden_div").html()
  );
</script>
```